# iTerm2 clear screen except actual command

Tags: iterm, fish

In iTerm2 `cmd + K` clears the complete screen. Is there a way to use this during a running command, so that everything gets delete except the current command and it's output?

Comment: What constitutes "during a running command"? There is `clear` which, as it's name suggests, clears screen including line containing clear command itself.

Comment: Consider the following scenario:

I run often `mvn test`. Now I want to clear the screen and remove everything from previous runs and keep the output from the current `mvn test` (command and output).

Comment: `clear && command goes here` works on some operation systems, but does not appear to do so in mac os. Clear just scrolls the terminal to the top, but keeps the scroll history.